# What's the quickest way to setup a socks proxy tunnel through ssh from Mac OS X?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks

Very often, I find myself on a network with poor international link or with access to certain websites blocked. I already manage several VPS with much better connection to the outside world, and I'd like to quickly create a tunnel from my MacBook that piggybacks on that connection.

Normally, I will `ssh` to the VPS host, then set up a SOCKS proxy from the Network Preferences Pane. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command-line:

```
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy wi-fi 127.0.0.1 1080; ssh -D1080 <host>; networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi off
```

replacing `<host>` with your VPS IP.

Once finished, press `Ctrl-D` to end the connection and have the teardown script deactivate the proxy setting.